# Do Advaita Vedanta followers perform rituals and rites?

Tags: advaita, vedanta

Do the followers of Advaita Vedanta believe in performing rituals like Yagna, Puja, Darshan, Mantra upchaar etc???

Comment: Good point.  Uttara mimamsa advaitins householders perform all samskaras. The totally emancipated sadhus though are free of all ritual , like for Sri Ramakrishna or Sri Ramana maharshi. If they want to perform a rite , they are free to.

Comment: They are not bound for all that. Its like asking do Buddhists pray to god.